Does changing workspace affect render?

I recently changed my workspace settings and saved it to be default. But now whenever I open Blender, the render window pops open as well. Even at a new project. I have tried re-saving a workspace with a rendering tab, but it still pops open a new window. Mind you, I do want a separate Render window for when I do actual renders, but not when I am just opening Blender. Any suggestions?

The pop-up render window should only be triggered by pressing F12 and actually doing a render. However, if you did have the pop-up window open whenever you saved your template it will open the render pop-up by default. I'd try adding the render tab and then making sure all other windows are closed before saving it as your default.

That's exactly what I did as I mentioned above, but the render tab still pops up whenever I open Blender

I'm not sure then. That doesn't make sense to me. Maybe check bug-reports on the Blender Github page to see if there's anything else similar that's been reported.
